# VideoJS: not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, video.js

I used the videojs and it is working fine all browsers(including IE) and on Android . But it is not working on IOS devices (iphone and ipad IOS version 6).

Here is the code which I am using to add the video to the page.

```
<video id="video1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="276" height="153" controls="" preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
<source src=myvideo.mp4 type="video/m4v" >
</video>
```

I have spent ages and could not find any solution. 
I m using video.js Version 3.2.0 and getting the loading spinner forever.
I tried using version 4 and just black screen comes up.

Any Help please.

Comment: have you confirmed the file can be played by ios?

Comment: Although this is not the case with the particular question, in case somebody else comes into this, iOS does not support autoplay: http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/922-autoplay-on-ipad-does-not-work-without-controls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First put double quotes around the source src attribute and try that. If that doesn't solve it, it sounds like the problem is with the mp4 itself, most likely because of the way it's been encoded or it has a huge filesize. Try using videojs's default movie (http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4) and see if that works. If it works, you know the problem lies with the movie file itself.

Comment: but it is working in all devices/all browsers but not in IE9 .

Comment: Yes there seems to be a slight problem with the current release of videojs. Take a look at my tutorial here which makes videojs abit more mobile friendly = http://www.andy-howard.com/recreate-bbc-iplayer/index.html

This uses the slightly older version of videojs (about 1 month ago), but it works in all browsers and smartphones.

Comment: For any future peoples, I converted FLV to MP4 (not sure of codec) but I can't play it on iPad in VideoJS BUT I can play MP4 on VideoJS's homepage.  Clearly a codec problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your web server should support byte-range requests,check whether web server support 206 response. If you are using nginx,add mp4 module.

Comment: I didn't try this exactly, but by hosting the video on AWS S3 rather than my own server, the video started to work on iOS devices. It definitely seems like server configuration will affect whether the video plays or not.

Answer (score 3):

I solved most of my mp4 encoding issues using [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: handbrake rocks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type="video/m4v" to "video/mp4".

```
<video class="video-js">
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

[Offical docs.](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-setup.html)