# VideoJS: not working on ipad

Tags: ios, html, ipad, salesforce, video.js

While trying to embed html5 `<video>` tag in my salesforce web Page, I came across a wonderful library called "Videojs" (http://videojs.com/getting-started/). It served most of the purpose, however when I tried to play a video on Ipad, it failed. Then I came across this link ([VideoJS: not working on IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720816/videojs-not-working-on-ios?newreg=f31f46b6a7294e80b70146c44cc27b77)), which says to try to use videojs's default movie as there possibly could be encoding issue. When I did as per the suggestion, I came with a very interesting scenario. As When I fed the url(http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4) directly as:

```
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

it worked fine both in windows and in ios. But when I downloaded the same video and saved it to Salesforce CRM Content libraries and gave the src path as:

```
<source src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/id" type="video/mp4" />
```

it worked in windows desktop browsers but not on ipad(version 9.2). I couldn't understand the issue.

Thanks for any help/ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Do you know what mime type the file has when returned by Salesforce CRM?  The iPad is very fussy about videos in HTML5: if anything is incorrect it seems to just ignore it, whereas many desktop browsers will guess what was intended and carry on.

Comment: Here is the entire response header: 
**Cache-Control private
Content-Disposition attachment; filename="oceans.mp4"
Content-Length 23014356
Content-Type video/mp4;charset=UTF-8
Date Tue, 05 Apr 2016 11:19:15 GMT**

Comment: Your problem is that the server must allow the iPad to fetch partial files, by including the Accept-Ranges header.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511006/html5-video-not-working-on-ipad)

Comment: Yes, I indeed went through that link. However as I said, when I fed the url directly
`<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />` it worked fine on windows and ios both. And the response header : **Age 0
Cache-Control max-age=31536000
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Length 23014356
Content-Type video/mp4
Date Tue, 05 Apr 2016 11:46:26 GMT
Etag "2125298091532905922013119cc3d2e9"
Last-Modified Wed, 08 May 2013 00:34:04 GMT
X-Cache MISS
X-Cache-Hits 0
X-Served-By cache-sin6920-SIN**. This response too doesn't contain Accept-Ranges.

Comment: That's presumably because the zencdn server supports partial files.  I don't think there is any way to get it to work unless the server provides the Accept-Ranges header and supports partial files.  I've run into the same problem serving video from a database and had to code in complete support for partial files to get the iPad to work.

Comment: Thank you @Stuart. I got your point. But unfortunately I don't have a control over salesforce server which feeds me the response.

Comment: You might be stuck.  I think the iPad simply won't play the video unless the server supports partial files.  iPads are a real pain!

Answer (score 2):

I am googling mostly encoding issue for mp4 file or hugesize file,so use   handbreak (https://handbrake.fr/). solve the problem