# VideoJs is not working with IOS [The media could not be loaded]

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, video.js

First of all, Yes i have searched for answers for this questions on stackoverflow ([for example this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720816/videojs-not-working-on-ios)) but it did not help me or maybe i'm just a noob..
I am trying to stream a video on my server via php/html5 here's the code example :

```
    <?php
$videourl = $_GET['url'];
$videothumb = $_GET['thumb'];
$scripturl = "\"script.php?url=$videourl\"";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <title>Watching <?php echo ($videoname); ?></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .d1 {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .d2 {
        text-align:center;
    }
    .d3 {
        text-align:right;
    }
    .copy {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .copy, .d3 {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .center { margin: 0 auto; width: 400px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video
            id="my-video"
            class="video-js"
            controls
            preload="metadata"
            suppressNotSupportedError='true'
            playsinline
            width="640"
            height="264"
            poster=<?php echo ($videothumb);?>
            data-setup="{}"
            >
            <source src=<?php echo ($scripturl);?> type="video/mp4" />
            <p class="vjs-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
                web browser that
                <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
                >supports HTML5 video</a>
            </p>
        </video>
    </div>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.10.2/video.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the script.php file is :

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36";
$v = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 222222);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$info = curl_exec($ch);
$size2 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
$filesize = $size2;
$offset = 0;
$length = $filesize;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $partialContent = "true";
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $length = $size2 - $offset - 1;
} else {
    $partialContent = "false";
}
if ($partialContent == "true") {
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    header('Content-Range: bytes '.$offset.
        '-'.($offset + $length).
        '/'.$filesize);
} else {
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
}
header("Content-length: ".$size2);


$ch = curl_init();
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    // if the HTTP_RANGE header is set we're dealing with partial content
    $partialContent = true;
    // find the requested range
    // this might be too simplistic, apparently the client can request
    // multiple ranges, which can become pretty complex, so ignore it for now
    preg_match('/bytes=(\d+)-(\d+)?/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $matches);
    $offset = intval($matches[1]);
    $length = $filesize - $offset - 1;
    $headers = array(
        'Range: bytes='.$offset.
        '-'.($offset + $length).
        ''
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 222222);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $v);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

The code works just fine for (Desktop and Android) but for IOS i get this :
**the media could not be loaded either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported**

on my ios device (Iphone 7 plus running ios 12 and iphone x running ios 14)
There might be something wrong that i'm doing but i tried all the answers here or on [videojs repo](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/4751)

Any help would be appreciated..

**edit:**
A link for testing :

[video file](https://ibotcorp.com/api/fushaar/video.mp4)

[stream code](https://ibotcorp.com/api/fushaar/stream.php?thumb=http://cima4u.io/wp-content/uploads/02-858.jpg&url=https://ibotcorp.com/api/fushaar/video.mp4)

Comment: Hmmm...maybe try on MacOS, too.  ( I know that Apple devices are known not to support a few video file types that other platforms do support.  That said, I don't tend to test my web-pages on Apple devices simply because I don't own any.  But, I believe there are 'virtual' ways of testing for platforms/OSes without having a real such device available to you. )

Comment: It does not work on apple mobile phones generally, i don't know why